# Powershell Out-File force end of line character

Tags: powershell, newline

I discovered that I could force a Unicode file to ASCII using the script below, which is *really* great.  I assume it's based on my environment or Windows default, but it's adding a CR and LF at the end of each line.  Is there a way to force just a LF character rather than both without loading the entire file into memory?  I have seen some solutions that load the entire file into memory and basically do a string replace, which won't work because some of my files are multiple GB.

Thanks!

```
get-content -encoding utf8 $inputFile | Out-file -force -encoding ASCII $outputFile
```

Comment: No. I mean - someone *has* to load the contents into memory in order to locate the line endings and replace them. If your files are that huge, PowerShell may not be the best option

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use .NET `System.File.IO` classes from within your script. In particular the `System.File.IO.StreamWriter` class has a property, `NewLine` which you can set to whatever characters you want the line terminator characters to be. (Although to be readable by `StreamReader` the line terminator chars must be `\n` or `\r\n` (in C/C++ notation because of conflict with SO and PS on backtick)).

Secondary benefit of using IO.StreamWriter, according to this [blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx) is much better perf.

Basic code flow is something like this (not tested):

```
# Note that IO.StreamWriter will use process's current working directory,
#  not PS's. So safer to specify full paths
$inStream =  [System.IO.StreamReader] "c:\temp\orig.txt"
$outStream = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter "c:\temp\copy.txt",  
                                               [text.encoding]::ASCII
$outStream.NewLine = '`n'
while (-not $inStream.endofstream) {
  $outStream.WriteLine( $instream.Readline())
}
$inStream.close()
$outStream.close()
```

This script should have constant memory requirements, but hard to know what .NET might do under the covers.